# Dropdown menus in MVC approach

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to understand this existing php code that displays drop down menus with their subsequent menus. while the code works in one level, i am having a hard time how to or what to add another level of the dropdown... i have been able to do that but in this case where php is used to display these fields, it's kind of mind-boggling for me... here's the existing code in the view side -->

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <?php
                        foreach ($nav as $item) {
                            if (empty($item['children'])) {
                            ?>
                                    <li<?php if (!empty($item['is_active'])) { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $item['link']; ?>"><?php if ($item['icon'] != '') { ?>
                                    <i class="<?php echo $item['icon']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="A large tooltip."></i>&nbsp; <?php } echo $item['label']; ?></a></li>
                            <?php
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                            ?>
                                <li class="dropdown <?php if (!empty($item['is_active'])) { ?> active<?php } ?>">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
                                        <?php if ($item['icon'] != '') { ?>
                                            <i class="<?php echo $item['icon']; ?>"></i>
                                        &nbsp;<?php  echo $item['label']; ?>
                                        <b class="caret"></b><?php } ?>
                                    </a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                                <?php
                                            _main_menu_widget_display_children($item['children']);
                                ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            <?php                   
                            }
                    }               
                ?>
```

and the controller looks like this -->

```
 $nav['settings']       = array('label' => 'Settings', 'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg',   );
$nav['settings/access_rights']  = array('label' => 'Approver',  'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg', 
                                'location' => site_url('admin/access_rights'), 'parent_id' => 'settings');          
            //separator
            $nav['settings/separator_1']    = array('blank' => true, 'parent_id' => 'settings');

            $nav['settings/billing_param']  = array('label' => 'Technician',    'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg', 
                                'location' => site_url('billing_param'), 'parent_id' => 'settings');
            //separator
            $nav['settings/separator_2']    = array('blank' => true, 'parent_id' => 'settings');

            $nav['settings/support_settings']   = array('label' => 'Support',   'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg', 
                                'location' => site_url('support_settings'), 'parent_id' => 'settings');
            //sub-menu sub of Support
            $nav['example1']    = array('label' => 'Request Supportt',  'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg', 
                                'location' => '#', 'parent_id' => 'settings/support_settings');
            $nav['example2']    = array('label' => 'Need Features',     'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg', 
                                'location' => '#', 'parent_id' => 'settings/support_settings');
            $nav['example3']    = array('label' => 'Telephone Number',  'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg', 
                                'location' => '#', 'parent_id' => 'settings/support_settings');
            $nav['example4']    = array('label' => 'Testimonials',  'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg', 
                                'location' => '#', 'parent_id' => 'settings/support_settings');
            $nav['example6']    = array('label' => 'Known Issues',  'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg', 
                                'location' => '#', 'parent_id' => 'settings/support_settings');
            $nav['example5']    = array('label' => 'Road Map',  'icon' => 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg', 
                                'location' => '#', 'parent_id' => 'settings/support_settings');
```

here's what it looks like :[image]

i just wanted those list under 'support' not shown when i clicked the 'settings' menu but rather after i hover or clicked (it doesnt matter really) the 'support' sub-menu... 
 i know there's something missing in the 'view' side but i dont know what is... another if-else maybe but i cant see any connection so far... any help is very much appreciated thanks... :)

Comment: Can't you just use CSS to hide the `.dropdown-menu` ul element and then when its parent li is hovered over you un-hide the menu?